# How do I quickly enter tally chart data into Excel where each tally mark becomes one row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have collected tally chart data for the measured length of a number of the same part.

For example, I have 92 tally marks for 56.11mm, 75 tally marks for 56.12mm, 63 tally marks for 56.13mm and so on.

In order to analyse the data I wish to have a row in excel for each measurement. So for the above example I would have 92 rows with 56.11, 75 rows with 56.12 etc.

How can I quickly enter this data into excel in the format I require?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name Box may be your best bet here - it's the box in the upper left of your worksheet, between the column headers and the ribbon, which shows the currently active cell address:

[image]

Click in there and replace "A1" with "A1:A92" and hit enter. This will select the appropriate rows. Then, without clicking anywhere else, type in the measurement you want and hit Ctrl+Enter. The value will be placed in all the highlight cells. You can repeat this for as many sets as you need.

Next option would be this macro:

```
Sub InsertCount()
    Dim varInsert As Variant
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim rngInsert As Range

    varInsert = InputBox("What value do you want to repeat?")
    lngCount = InputBox("How many times?")

    If Len(varInsert) > 0 And _
        lngCount > 0 Then
        If Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
            Set rngInsert = Range("A1", "A" & lngCount)
        Else
            Set rngInsert = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lngCount, 1)
        End If
        rngInsert.Value = varInsert
    End If
End Sub
```

It will ask you what value you want to insert, then how many times to insert it, then put that value into the first free row of column A and repeat it as many times as necessary.